# I want to fix the json pattern while sending the post request

Tags: rest, spring-boot

```
{"vehicle_number": "KA222009","vehicle_type":"sedan"}
```

This json I am sending a POST request and it gets saved !! I have used Request body serverside in spring boot so its fine up to here but when I send like

```
{"vehicle_number": "KA222009","vehicle_type":"sedan","username":"abc"}
```

this also gets saved with the matching attribute of my RequestBody class. I don't want in this way and restrict the user to play with the request. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entity to save that request into? Like

```
class Vehicle{
String vehicle_number;
String vehicle_type;
}
```

You'd need to put in the parameters then something like this

```
myfunction(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle)
```

I believe an exception should be thrown by then.

**edit 1:**

The class Vehicle should be annotated with `@Entity`

And it's good practice to return a `ReponseEntity<?>` instead of actual data types

**edit 2:**

On another note, if you want your Vehicle entity to have a username but restrict the user from changing the username, then you just have to exclude it from the Vehicle constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Rei Brown's answer, you will likely not only want to create a data class, you will also want [Bean Validation](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators) on it. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(/*....*/)
public void save(@Valid @RequestBody Vehicle vehicle){ 
    // ... save logic here
}
```